# How can I use optional attributes on an object using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have several attributes on a Player model. My form contains fields for a player to be added. I want to have optional fields where a second player can enter their name, and rather than having to retype the address and other things for the second player, I want the second player to inherit all the other information that the first player entered without having to type it in again. How can I do this?
**players/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @player, html: {class: "horizontal-form"} do |player| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :first_name, "First Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :last_name, "Last Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :address, "Address", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :address, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :city, "City", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :city, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :state, "State", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%> 
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :state, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :zip_code, "Zip Code", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :zip_code, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :email, "Email", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= player.text_field :email, class: "form-control", :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
      <%= player.label :veteran, "Veteran", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="checkbox col-sm-offset-3">
        <%= player.check_box :veteran %>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class = row>
    <%= player.label :branch_id, "Branch", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= player.collection_select(:branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <%= player.submit 'Submit', class: 'col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: 2 solutions that come to mind are, A. use javascript to override the submit and if the second player enters a name, submit the same data for both players.  B. update the controller action to check for the second player name presence, and duplicate the data for that player.  Of the 2 the first is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will try those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a `javascript` question than a `RoR` one.

Assuming you want them to have the option to fill in different information, the easiest way I can think to do this is to have a bunch of hidden fields for the player two information (other than their name), give the player one fields `onkeypress` events that would call a function that would take in the id of the corresponding player two field and use that to find the hidden player two field and fill in their html to be the same as the field you're currently filling in, something like

```
function fillPlayerTwoField(id) {
  $(id).text(this.value)
}
```

then if they start filling in the player two name unhide all the player two fields so the have the option to change that information if they so choose